# SVG from web to illustrator

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

Im looking to make a system in which a user can create simple shapes and text on the web using SVG. I'd then like to be able to save whatever they've done to a database so they can come back and edit further, and/or be able to export what they've created from the database into illustrator.

Is there one particular library or approach that would make doing this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

This may send you in the right direction [SVG-Edit project](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit).

If you just need a good svg framework to write your own, [svg.js](http://svgjs.com) has always been good to me.

Good luck.